# HydraDragon Columnar Storage on Apache Ignite

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I just came upon the announcement of the HydraDragon columnar storage engine for Apache Ignite on GridGain's blog (October 27, 2021).

It is not clear if it will be available in the community edition of GridGain or only in a paying version.

Could you please clarify ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HydraDragon will be available for all Apache Ignite and GridGain applications using [GridGain Nebula](https://www.gridgain.com/products/gridgain-nebula). That's known for sure. As for downloadable versions such as Community, Enterprise, or other editions - that information will be shared publicly later.